# After starting Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I Started Rails and it give me this error below,

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in HomeController#index

Could not find table 'users'

What is this error what does it mean what do i have to to do next to get rails working.

Comment: I'd still recommend finding a tutorial.

Comment: Here's the official Getting Started for Rails. It covers your question as well as others that you may have. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: I seldom answer basic questions from newcomers, so please don't forget to accept the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means your database has not the proper `users` table.

To fix it, you have to migrate it:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy, you really solved the entire issue :)
 just that the syntax had a little error rake:db:migrate to be replaced with 
rake db:migrate

Comment: Im trying to create a blog its just not letting me do so.
what could be possible easy step to create a blog?